# EFcore 5, MySQL, longtext column, content greater 4 M(!)B raises error

Tags: mysql, ef-core-5.0

I am using "EF core 5.0.9" and MySQL and have a table which contains also this column

```
`Blob` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Entities are writen/stored in the database as follows:

```
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The saving works fine until the entity.blob value is greater than around 4 Mega(!)Bytes.
Shown error message:
"An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine."

The error is not content dependent but length dependent.
The error also occurs when the content is exchanged with more than 4 million 'x' characters. 

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of this setting : [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) ?   (`show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';`)

Comment: @Luuk `SELECT SESSION max_allowed_packet;` seems to be more clear.

Comment: @Luuk3 Thank you very much! The value was set in my.ini to 4 MB. I´ve changed it to 16M, restarted the MySQL service and it worked fine. Again: Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Akina: that is why I linked to the docs. Reading the docs I see: "The session value of this variable is read only", so changes cannot be done to the session varable.

Comment: @Luuk In common the account must not have privileges for global options edition. The changes made in one session may effect another session, even with some unpleasant consequences. The settings file should be edited accordingly - edited by the server administrator. I.e. look, and, if not safe for you, call admin.

Comment: To point it again out: I was and am very pleased with Luuks answers! He provided the parameter name and on top of this the link to the documentation - more than enough / expected!! Again: Thank you very much Luuk!